# A good starting position for maximizing a function with Newton-Raphson / Halley's method

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-theory

I'm attempting to find the maximum of this function:

\begin{align*}
h(\mathbf{t}) = -\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}_i^\intercal \mathbf{t}}\right\} + \boldsymbol{\alpha}^\intercal \mathbf{t} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^\intercal \Gamma \mathbf{t}
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_i \ge 0$ and $\Gamma$ is symmetric, positive definite (this guarantees $h$ is everywhere concave, and so a unique max exists). I plan to find the solution via Newton-Raphson / Halley's method, which require a sufficiently close starting point $t_0$. If we analyze the derivative,
\begin{align*}
\nabla h(\mathbf{t}) = -\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i \boldsymbol{\theta}_ie^{\boldsymbol{\theta}_i^\intercal \mathbf{t}}\right\} + \boldsymbol{\alpha} - \Gamma \mathbf{t}
\end{align*}
Now, if $n = 1$, then it turns out the solution is (based off some help from a previous [Overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287826/multivariate-solution-to-lambert-w-product-log-function)):
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{\mathbf{t}} = \Gamma^{-1}\boldsymbol{\alpha} - \frac{W(\lambda\boldsymbol{\theta}^\intercal\Gamma^{-1}\boldsymbol{\theta} e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}^\intercal \Gamma^{-1}\boldsymbol{\alpha}})}{\boldsymbol{\theta}^\intercal\Gamma^{-1}\boldsymbol{\theta}}\Gamma^{-1}\boldsymbol{\theta}
\end{align*}
where $W$ is the lambert $W$ function along the zero branch, for which there are [great initial approximations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0735.pdf) for.

I tried adapting the strategy in the above paper to my case, but couldn't proceed further. Please advise a quick, dirty initial approximation to my objective function.

Comment: Hi Tom, I've come across effectively the same optimization problem in my own work, did you ever find a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try applying [gradient ascent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) method and run it for a few iterations to get an initial guess for $\mathbf{t}$. As the function is strongly concave, the gradient ascent is sure to converge to its unique global maxima, and so running it for a few iterations will produce a good approximation for the true global maxima. Actually, by analyzing the gradient ascent steps, you can estimate how many iterations you need to run it for the approximation to meet a prespecified approximation error required for the Newton-Raphson/Halley method to succeed. See [this](https://rkganti.wordpress.com/2015/08/24/gradient-descent-on-strongly-convex-functions/) for such a discussion.