# Multivariate fixed point of a function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The fixed-point of a vector-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a value $\textbf{b}$ such that $f(\textbf{b}) = \textbf{b}$ (this value is not necessarily unique). Any ideas on how to compute the multivariate fixed point for the following function
\begin{align*}
f(\textbf{b}) = \Gamma^{-1}\textbf{z}\left(y - \frac{e^{\textbf{z}^\intercal \textbf{b}}}{c + e^{\textbf{z}^\intercal \textbf{b}}}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\textbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $y \in \{0, 1\}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$? You can see from one of my [previous posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287826/multivariate-solution-to-lambert-w-product-log-function) of a similar question, which is similar in nature and express something in terms of the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: So, uh, what is "generalized" about your definition of a fixed point? And are you interested in a closed form expression for the fixed point? Because otherwise, Newton's method for $g(b) := f(b)-b$?

Comment: Apologies, I would like a closed-form solution for the fixed point, if possible. Solving for this fixed-point is part of several layers of other optimizations going on, so I would like this to be as fast as possible.

Comment: What does $\Gamma$ mean here?

Comment: $\Gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is positive-definite symmetric

Comment: @Hannes Also, I corrected the generalized to just a fixed point. I realize what you mean, since a fixed point is just fixed point, but I meant "generalized" here in the context of multivariate.

Answer (score 1):

The right side is a scalar multiple of $\Gamma^{-1} {\bf z}$, and its dependence on $\bf b$ is only through ${\bf z} ^\intercal  \bf b$, so this is really just a one-dimensional problem.  Let ${\bf a} = \Gamma^{-1} {\bf z}$ and $k = {\bf z}^\intercal \bf a$.  Then with ${\bf b} = x \bf a$, the fixed-point equation $f({\bf b}) = \bf b$ becomes
$$x = y - \frac{e^{k x}}{c + e^{kx}}$$
AFAIK this does not have closed-form solutions (even using LambertW).